# How to use perldb's x command from within user code?

Tags: perl, pretty-print

What's the programmatic equivalent of the perl debugger's `x` command?

IOW, what's the function `x` such that the line

```
print x( $myvar );
```

in a Perl script will result in output with the same format as that produced by

```
DB<2> x $myvar
```

in the perl debugger?

(**NOTE**: I'm aware of `Data::Dumper`, and it is *not* what I'm looking for; IOW, I'm explicitly ruling it out; `D::D`'s formatting differs from that produced by the debugger's `x`, and I prefer the latter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the routines in `dumpvar.pl`, which you will find in the same directory as your `perl5db.pl` file (cf. `perldoc -l perl5db.pl`).

Example:

```
require "dumpvar.pl";
dumpValue( { foo => 123, bar => "qwerty" } );
```

Produces:

```
'bar' => 'qwerty'
'foo' => 123
```

Comment: a) no need for fullpath to dumpvar.pl; b) no need for `print`, either.  `perl -e 'require "dumpvar.pl"; dumpValue({foo=>123,bar=>"qwerty"})'` works.